# How to make every vehicle do something in Or Tools?

Tags: python, c#, traveling-salesman, or-tools, vehicle-routing

In several problems of the VRP, when informing the total number of vehicles, it is compromised that all are used and that at least they visit a node. In reality, this may not even be the best, but I would like to understand why and how to adapt according to needs.
The example below concerns the simple VRP example according to OR Tools, with a small edition in the distance matrix and some changes according to the website (blog) - https://activimetrics.com/blog/ortools/counting_dimension /. According to the latter, it is possible to carry out a fair distribution of routes, which seemed totally appealing, since, as a rule, the solver minimizes the longest route and ends up using fewer vehicles and assigning several nodes to it. An important need was the use of an approach that makes the vehicle act, ensuring that it is used at least once.
However, if 5 vehicles are used to solve the problem, by logic and result obtained, he gets there, places a node for each vehicle, which without this edition was not possible. The problem is that using only 4 vehicles, the solver is no longer there, it manages to distribute routes, but always leaves a vehicle out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.OrTools.ConstraintSolver;

public class VrpGlobalSpan
{
    class DataModel
    {      
        public long[,] DistanceMatrix = {
        {0, 9777, 10050,7908,10867,16601},
        {9777, 0, 4763, 4855, 19567,31500},
        {10050, 4763,0,2622,11733,35989},
        {7908,4855,2622,0,10966,27877},
        {10867,19567,11733,10966,0,27795},
        {16601,31500,35989,27877,27795,0},
    };
        public int VehicleNumber = 4;
        public int Depot = 0;
    };

    /// <summary>
    ///   Print the solution.
    /// </summary>
    static void PrintSolution(
        in DataModel data,
        in RoutingModel routing,
        in RoutingIndexManager manager,
        in Assignment solution)
    {
        // Inspect solution.
        long maxRouteDistance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Route for Vehicle {0}:", i);
            long routeDistance = 0;
            var index = routing.Start(i);
            while (routing.IsEnd(index) == false)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} -> ", manager.IndexToNode((int)index));
                var previousIndex = index;
                index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index));
                routeDistance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previousIndex, index, 0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", manager.IndexToNode((int)index));
            Console.WriteLine("Distance of the route: {0}m", routeDistance);
            maxRouteDistance = Math.Max(routeDistance, maxRouteDistance);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Maximum distance of the routes: {0}m", maxRouteDistance);
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate the data problem.
        DataModel data = new DataModel();

        // Create Routing Index Manager
        RoutingIndexManager manager = new RoutingIndexManager(
            data.DistanceMatrix.GetLength(0),
            data.VehicleNumber,
            data.Depot);

        // Create Routing Model.
        RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(manager);

        // Create and register a transit callback.
        int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(
            (long fromIndex, long toIndex) => {
            // Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
            var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
                var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);
                return data.DistanceMatrix[fromNode, toNode];
            }
            );

        // Define cost of each arc.
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);
        
        double answer = 5/data.VehicleNumber +1;
        //double Math.Ceiling(answer);
        //double floor = (int)Math.Ceiling(answer);
        routing.AddConstantDimension(
            1,
            (int)Math.Ceiling(answer),
            true,  // start cumul to zero
            "Distance") ;
        RoutingDimension distanceDimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("Distance");
        //distanceDimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.VehicleNumber; ++i)
        {
            distanceDimension.SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(routing.End(i), 2, 1000000);
        }
        // Setting first solution heuristic.
        RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters =
          operations_research_constraint_solver.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
        //searchParameters.FirstSolutionStrategy =
        //  FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PathCheapestArc;
        searchParameters.TimeLimit = new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Duration { Seconds = 5 }; 
        searchParameters.LocalSearchMetaheuristic = LocalSearchMetaheuristic.Types.Value.Automatic;       

        // Solve the problem.
        Assignment solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);

        // Print solution on console.
        PrintSolution(data, routing, manager, solution);
    }
}
```

Perhaps it must have been a topic already discussed, but I wanted to understand and understand what is the best path to follow and what measures to take to transform this example and others to follow in a better approach.
I thank you in advance for your attention and I am waiting for feedback.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you found an answer yet?